# default.realm file is not display in the chrome browser

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, realm, stetho

I follow : [This is from Facebook documentation.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html)

Debugging with `Stetho` on Android.

[image: Debugging with Stetho on Android]

I run `react-native run-android` via terminal.

Then, Inspect with `Chrome Developer Tools` and then `Developer Tools`

[image]

After i inspect, `Resources/Web Sql/` display empty.

My realm file is in : `path: /data/data/com.demo/files/default.realm`.

What can be done to view my `default.realm` file in chrome browser?

Comment: Change the name of the realm database:                                  RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("base.realm")

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but i resolved by changing stetho version to `'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.1'` also make sure you will initialize stetho properly like this

```
Stetho.initialize(
Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
.enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this))
.enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this))
nableWebKitInspector(RealmInspectorModulesProvider.builder(this).build())
.build());
```